# SharePoint 2013 S2S Configuration with Exchange

Tags: security, exchange, ediscovery, site-mailboxes

I am trying to configure Site Mailboxes and eDiscovery between SharePoint 2013 and Exchange 2013. The guidance on both of these is pretty much the same, create a server to server trust, then grant permissions to the AppPrincipal.

Here are the instructions for eDiscovery for SharePoint and Exchange:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj655399.aspx

All the various pre-reqs seem to be met (UPS sync and MySites configured, Work Management and App Management service apps provisioned, etc). I am using SSL everywhere with certs issues from AD Cert Services, etc.

The problem I am getting is that when I create my SPTrustedSecurityTokenIssuer and then examine the registration, the .NameID property is blank. Unfortunately, the remaining instructions for granting permissions to AppPrincipcal require this property, and I am not sure why mine is blank.

[image]

Anyone have any idea why this property is blank, and how I might fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TechNet documentation is wrong. Do not use -IsTrustBroker parameter when creating trusted token issuer.